# Battery slowly charging on Tab S

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, battery, charging, tablet

I have a tablet Samsung SM T-805 (Tab S 10.5"). Also I have Samsung A5 2016 phone and original Samsung adapter (2A 5V).

I had custom OS installed on my tablet. At some moment it became to charge really slow. So I have installed Android M on my Tab S. Also I installed 3C battery monitor. **First** charge after reistalling was fast. In fact it was close to 2A. But now charging rate is only 0.5A. Also 3C shows that battery is in good state.

I don't think that problem is with cable/adapter: A5 shows 1A current while charging (I think it's limit for it).

What I suspect:

1. Usb plug-in is damaged.
2. Android is limiting charge rate. I think it's more likely since battery had charged faster right after reinstalling Android.

In case 2 there might be a possibility to somehow remove that limit, but how? If it requires root access it's not a problem.

Comment: Your Tablet needs a fast charger, i guess (5V 2A) isn't enough for it to charge your device quickly, also power off your device while charging it will speed up the charging process

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui, the weird thing is that tablet receive less current than phone. Powering off speeds up process only for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have approx 300 Samsung tablets in my company (including ~100 SM-T805). I understand that this could be a software issue with your ROM etc, but in our experience, we often do find that the cables can slowly degrade over time, and even though they display that they are charging at full speed, the speed is actually well below the original maximum.

*I would suggest you find an alternative cable to test*. Drain the tablet battery to 0%, power the unit down and test a full charge with the current cable, (e.g. 2hr 12mins) and then replace the cable, and re-charge the tablet from 0% again.